Vue - Is there a way for a route to have the same path, but different name (at least for test purpose only)?
I have the following vue-router definition in my vue app:
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/test/:id',
    name: 'test',
    component: () => import('@/components/MyComponent.vue')
  }
]

And in my vue component, I use the onBeforeRouteUpdate hook to perform some logic, if the path params (id) changes, but the name of the route stays the same.
onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from, next) => {
  console.log('onBeforeRouteUpdate triggered')
  if (to.name === from.name) { // need to cover the else path
    next();
    doSomething()
  }
});

This implementation works fine. The problem is, I need to have full test coverage, and the else path for if (to.name === from.name) { is not being covered. I am using vitest 1.4.0 and istanbul as the coverage provider.
Here is what my attempt at covering the else statement looks like. This snippet does not look to be triggering the onBeforeRouteUpdate hook at all.
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let router
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(),
      routes: [
        ...routes,
        {
          path: '/test/:id',
          name: 'test-fake',
          component: '<div />'
        }
      ]
    })
  })
  
  test('nothing happens for same route with different names', async () => {
    wrapper = mount(() => h('div', {}, [h(RouterView), h(MyComponent)]), {
      global: {plugins: [router]}
    })

    // navigate to /test/123
    router.push({
      name: 'test',
      params: {
        id: '123'
      }
    })
    await router.isReady()


    // navigate to the same route, but with a different name
    // /test/-1
    router.push({
      name: 'test-fake',
      params: {
        id: '-1'
      }
    })

    await flushPromises()
    // assertions
  })
})

What could be done so that the else path gets covered? I am limited to only using vue, vue-test-utils and vue-router.

Under which condition "name" would be different in onBeforeRouteUpdate?

onBeforeRouteUpdate() nav guard is called when the route changes, but the same component is used. I am assuming that there might come a case where the routes are the same, but the name is different. Not sure if it is possible at all.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards

I'm not sure if it's explained in the docs what these "reused components" are, but it's for tracking the changes within the same route, it's called on the updates of route params or probably child routes, but not different routes. If you use child routes, you can test this.
